# YOLO v5 labelling dilemma

Tags: cnn, object-detection, yolo, labels, yolov5

let's say I want to detect 3 different types of objects in an image using transfer learning from YOLO v5.

I have only 1 custom input image, with over 2000 labels comprising of all these 3 unique classes/objects I want to identify. Why wouldn't this work? All the information is contained in a single image. How do I get the algorithm to extract that information and use it for transfer learning?

Would I have to have 1000+ images each with 10-20 labels instead? I'm trying to understand how I can make the algorithm learn from 1 image if all the labels are already contained in it and all the information is already there?